# Using list slicing and “+” operator how this work?

Tags: python, slice

```
S=len(s)
i=0
while i<S:
    fwd=s[i:]+s[1:i]
    print(fwd)
    i+=1
```

> I want to know the working of fwd = s[i:]+s[1:i]

Comment: Doesn't printing it show you what is going on?  After printing, what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: You need to explain each of the parts of: `fwd=s[i:]+s[1:i]` saying that you know what the part does, or you don't know what the part does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say that i = 2 and s = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. first it does s[2:](2, 3, 4, 5) + s1:2. then its [2, 3, 4] + [1] = [2, 3, 4, 1]